# Unable to mount a block partition from Windows to Android device

Tags: windows, mount, cifs

I am not able to mount an image over a network onto my Android device. I tried to pull the `userdata` partition onto my Windows using:

```
adb pull /dev/block/mm..0p29 userdata.img
```

Now, I am trying to mount this image on some other Android device over network using Samba/CIFS:

```
busybox mount -t cifs -o vers=1.0,username=...,pass=..."//ipaddr/folder" /mnt/folder
```

to mention I don't see the CIFS in my filesystems, so I tried to build a kernel with CIFS support but failed to have one. I tried to push an already built `cifs.ko` into `system/bin/modules` and load it, but it still doesn't show up in `/proc/filesystems`.

My device is rooted, I have tried using SambaDocumentsProvider/CIFSManager but even after clicking on mount option, I don't find any files shown via the file explorers.

I can't even see any mountpoint being shown. I have set my device to permissive to get rid of any SELinux issues.

if anyone knows how to fix it, please share it with me.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something. You cant directly mount an file-system image located at a cifs share. You first have to mount the cifs share (or a folder in it) and then you may be able to mount the file-system image.

Comment: yes i first want to mount a cifs share folder and i am unable to mount it. Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: android is encrypted is your partition image even mountable at all?